# How to create a Union the complicated way?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I stumbled upon this when playing around with compilation units.

I have 2 headers that define a class with the same name. The first compilation unit includes the first header and declares an extern pointer to the class, the second compilation unit includes the second header and defines the pointer.

Now I have T* pointing to an U.

mcve:

> h1.h

```
#pragma once
struct a_struct {
    int i;

    a_struct(int _i) : i{ _i } {}
};
```

> h2.h

```
#pragma once
struct a_struct {
    float f;

    a_struct(float _f) : f{ _f } {}
};
```

> foo.h

```
#pragma once
struct foo {
    int bar();
};
```

> cu1.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "h1.h"

extern a_struct* s;

int foo::bar() {
    return s->i;
}
```

> cu2.cpp

```
#include "h2.h"

a_struct* s = new a_struct(1.0f);
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    foo f;

    std::cout << f.bar() << std::endl; // <- 1065353216

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the linker see that h1.h::a_struct is not a h2.h::a_struct ? Is this mentioned in the standard as undefined behaviour ?

(Also I know naming 2 classes with the same name is stupid...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler *compiles* each source files separately. It trusts a given class declaration to be the same for all source files.

When you do as above, you trick the compiler into compiling two files with two different definition for some class. Each file generates a self-consistent piece of code.

Then the linker comes in and *links* your various bits of code together. There's an object/library format which is shared across all compilers. This is to allow every linker to work with every compiler. At this point, all the linker knows is that some code will pass a *foo* object and some other code will receive a *foo* object. It's not its business to go peek and check and complain.

Keep in mind that, at link-time, the source code might not even be available. You may have a library from some vendor without source code. And there might be various #defines that could have affected this object. The linker doesn't need to know what the compilation settings were, or even what the source was. The code could even have been written in another language.

To gain this flexibility and interoperability, there's some rules you have to follow. One of them is "don't define the same class twice in different ways".

Comment: Yes I had just updated my question, I meant the linker.

Comment: added paragraph 3, which may give insight.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this mentioned in the standard as undefined behaviour ?

Yes, this is a violation of the "header version" of the One Definition Rule. In this version, which applies to class definitions, `inline` functions and variables, and other such things commonly defined in header files, multiple definitions of a single entity are allowed in separate translation units, but those definitions must all have the same tokens (after preprocessing) and must all mean essentially the same thing. Multiple definitions which aren't the same in this way are undefined behavior. See [[basic.def.odr]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12) in the C++20 draft, and the fifth paragraph under [One Definition Rule at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule).

> Why doesn't the linker see that h1.h `::a_struct` is not a h2.h `::a_struct` ?

In most C++ implementations, the compiler converts a translation unit into an object file containing function code and symbol definitions, and the function code may make use of additional "undefined symbols" to be defined by other objects. By the point of an object file, little is saved about C++ source or type information, except possibly in debugger data. A linker will probably see just that function `foo::bar()` in cu1.o uses the undefined symbol `s`, cu2.o defines the symbol `s`, and the global-dynamic-initialization function of cu2.o also uses the symbol `s`. The linker will just adjust things so that executing `foo::bar()` will correctly access the same object `s`, without much caring what any function actually does with the bytes belonging to that symbol.

(Linkers can sometimes warn when object files disagree about the number of bytes associated with a symbol, but two pointers-to-class-type objects will probably have the same size.)